# Вывести структуру на экран

Tags: c++

Имеется вот такой код:

```
struct CField
{
    int m_type;
    std::vector<char> m_data;
};

struct CRecord
{
    std::vector<CField> m_fields;
};
```

вот так заполняю структуру,

```
char *bufOut = new char[pRecSize * pStr]; // Адрес буфера для присылаемых записей.

err = hcSqlReadResults(pOper, 0, bufOut, pRecSize * pStr, &cntOut); // Чтение результатов

char *p = bufOut; //  делаем указатель на массив

std::list<CRecord> records;

for (int i = 0; i < pStr; i++) // проход по строкам
{
    CRecord rec;
    rec.m_fields.reserve(pCol);

    for (int j = 0; j < pCol; j++) // по колонкам
    {
        CField field;
        field.m_type = infCol[j].type;
        field.m_data.insert(field.m_data.end(), p, p + infCol[j].len);
        rec.m_fields.emplace_back(std::move(field));

        p += infCol[j].len;
    }
    records.emplace_back(std::move(rec));                        
}
```

Подскажите как вывести на экран структуру?
Попробовал вот так:

```
std::copy( records.begin(), records.end(), 
std::ostream_iterator<std::string>( std::cout, " ") );
```

но ошибка

> Серьезность   Код Описание    Проект  Файл    Строка
>   Ошибка  C2679   бинарный "=": не найден оператор, принимающий правый операнд типа "CRecord" (или приемлемое преобразование отсутствует) AdmHyTech   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xutility 2148

Comment: Нужно написать свой оператор << для структуры

Comment: а как ?   и куда его вставить ?

Answer (score 3):

```
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, const Record& rec)
{
    out << " my record is";
    return out;
}
```

Comment: Эта функция должна быть внутри вашего класса CRecord

Comment: @DanielProtopopov нет, снаружи.

Comment: Да, я здесь это спутал с операторами типа *= где возвращается *this

Comment: сделал так   struct CRecord
{
 std::vector<CField> m_fields;

  std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, const  Record& rec)
 {
  out << " my record is";
  return out;
 } 
};

Comment: Ошибка C2143 синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие "," перед "&" AdmHyTech d:\__my_proj_hytech\!_my_soft_hytech_!\1_hytech_консоль(2)\admhytech\main.cpp 27

Comment: Ошибка C4430 отсутствует спецификатор типа - предполагается int. Примечание. C++ не поддерживает int по умолчанию AdmHyTech d:\__my_proj_hytech\!_my_soft_hytech_!\1_hytech_консоль(2)\admhytech\main.cpp 27

Comment: Ошибка C2804 бинарный "operator <<" имеет слишком много параметров AdmHyTech d:\__my_proj_hytech\!_my_soft_hytech_!\1_hytech_консоль(2)\admhytech\main.cpp 28

Comment: Ошибка C2333 CRecord::operator <<: ошибка в объявлении функции; пропуск основного текста функции AdmHyTech d:\__my_proj_hytech\!_my_soft_hytech_!\1_hytech_консоль(2)\admhytech\main.cpp 28

Comment: да сделал снаружи

Comment: а теперь как ?????

Comment: вот так 
 std::cout << records;